# Хедер при малом разрешении в сэндвич бутстраповский чтобы ( слева сэндвич справа, внутри меню плюс поиск) как лучше сделать в данном случае?

Tags: bootstrap, header, toggle

```css
.header {
  background: #fff;
  height: 90px;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  box-shadow: 0 -6px 10px;
}

.bar {
  padding-top: 10px;
}

.bar ul {
  padding: 0;
}

.bar a {
  font-weight: bold;
}

.logo_cake2 a {
  margin-right: 7px;
}

.menu li {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0 auto;
  margin: 0 auto;
}

.menu__item a {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.menu__item a {
  display: block;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 330;
  color: #5d5d5d;
  padding-top: 50px;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-transform: uppercase;
}

.menu__item a:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #b84747;
}

.soc-buttons {
  padding-left: 0 auto;
  padding-top: 28px;
  margin-left: -35px !important;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.soc-buttons a {
  margin: 2px;
}

.soc-buttons a:hover img {
  opacity: 0.3;
}

.shopping-bag {
  display: inline-block;
}

.cart hr {
  margin-top: 0px;
  margin-left: 10px;
  margin-right: -5px;
  height: 30px;
  width: 1px;
  background-color: #000;
  opacity: 0.8;
}

.cart {
  margin-left: 70px;
  padding-top: 29px;
  white-space: nowrap;
}

.header-search {
  padding-top: 2px;
}

.shopping-bag:hover {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #000;
  opacity: 0.5;
}

.search-field-container input {
  width: 80px;
}

.shopping-bag a {
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: lighter;
  list-style-type: none;
  text-decoration: none;
}

.icon img {
  margin-left: 15px;
  padding: 0 0 0;
}

.header-search input {
  margin-left: 8px;
  border: none;
  outline: none;
  font-family: "Fira Sans";
  font-weight: lighter;
  font-size: 16px;
}
```

```html
<header id="header" class="header fixed-top">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-3">
        <ul class="soc-buttons">
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191129" alt="Facebook" width="35" height="35"></a>
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191196" alt="Instagram" width="35" height="35"></a>
          <a href="#" target="_blank"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191176" alt="GooglePlus" width="35" height="35"></a>

          <!-- Модальное окно с номером -->
          <a href="#"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191246" alt="Viber" width="35" height="35"></a>
        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-6 bar center-block">
        <nav>
          <ul class="menu d-flex justify-content-center">
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="index.html">Головна</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="#">Продукція</a></li>
            <li class="logo_cake2">
              <a href="index.html"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319196163" alt="Main-logo" width="60" height="70"></a>
            </li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="index_aboutus.html">Про нас</a></li>
            <li class="menu__item"><a href="index_contacts.html">Контакти</a></li>
          </ul>
        </nav>
      </div>
      <div class="col-lg-3 ">
        <div class="cart d-flex justify-content-center">
          <ul class="shopping-bag">
            <a href="#"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191220" alt="Bag" width="25" height="30"></a>
          </ul>
          <div>
            <hr noshade>
          </div>
          <div data-role="search-menu" class="header-search d-flex justify-content-center">
            <a class="icon"><img src="https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319191207" alt="Searching" width=25 "" height="25"></a>
            <div class="dropdown">
              <fieldset data-role="search-autocomplete" class="search-autocomplete">
                <div class="search-field-container">

                  <input autocomplete="off" class="search-query" data-role="search-query" id="SearchQuery" name="SearchQuery" placeholder="Шукати" rel="" tooltip="Шукати розділи, товар..." type="text" value="">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-role="search-reset"></button>

                </div>
                <div class="search-results-container" data-role="search-results">
                  <ul class="list-unstyled search-results"></ul>
                </div>
              </fieldset>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>
```

Comment: https://fex.net/#!233826250821?fileId=319202350
Вот скрин как выглядит хедер.

Comment: Чтобы *Cлева сендвич, справа корзина а внутри меню плюс поиск "